# How to copy and output text from another textbox with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="hidden" id="prevTicketNo" value="6"/>

<script>
  var ticketNo = document.getElementById(prevTicketNo).value +1;
  document.getElementById('currentTicketNo').value = ticketNo;
</script>

<input id="currentTicketNo" value=""/>
```

What I am trying to do:
The prevTicketNo is a value captured from somewhere else. I need that to load as a hidden field so I used type="hidden". Once the value in this textbox is loaded, I need to +1 so that the number increases for my current ticket.

Is the right approach?

Comment: Nothing wrong in it but what do you intend to do with the current ticket number once populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the `value` of the first `input` to `integer`.

```
var ticketNo =parseInt((document.getElementById('prevTicketNo').value),10)+1;
document.getElementById('currentTicketNo').value = ticketNo;
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/amamuk/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
var hiddenVal = document.getElementById("prevTicketNo");
var newTicketNo = Number(hiddenVal.value) + 1;

alert(newTicketNo);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="prevTicketNo" value="6"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the previous ticket number and output it into a hidden field (obviously via some kind of server side script), why can't you just output it directly into your text input?
eg. In PHP write this:

```php
<input id="currentTicketNo" value="<?php echo $prevTicketNo + 1; ?>" />
```